# how to decode an encrypted text in <textarea> HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, decode

I have got a HTML webpage with a part of source code like this:

```html
<textarea style="display:none;">HjqUuzXfBIDVLPexdrFGvDONskpz0cugLPwQh35sTSTYjLJO+2Z7z4KF07FEmniNfrIv9lLvz7nK
ctjzklG8ftv7aJ+x2HSmYi/lppuvjnFdihEzA45/pi/6rS41JFENLhgR52cijftxAenTSZC8d3gE
....
iKMgSbikEpmv4FQ89fGKrAgRQkk4peoku9PaLvTzOgN7ZtY6BKAgyLI2oiFT33n0LOaT3i4/xl51
tBWagIXL5vctsHI+3uBlKgutIUo81DASBY4U0GcvI4YxQpqAs+jNj9qD0HAFkg==</textarea>
```

The texts with  tags are non-readable, but it should be a piece of HTML-compatible text. Tried to use Python str.decode("base64") and only got a piece of non-printable texts. How can I decode that piece of text within  HTML tag? Thanks~

Comment: Is this on your web page or in python?

Comment: Please show your code trying to read this.

Comment: this is in a HTML. I am trying to use Python to decode that part of code within <textarea> tags.

Comment: @Avery  My Python code goes like this:

    rec = re.compile("<textarea style=\"display:none;\">(.*?)</textarea>")
    m = rec.search(req.text)
    if m!= None:
        print m.group(1).decode("base64")

and only get something like following (only the first a few lines here):

:��5�d�N&V�糒�3~�o.N
\� @|�v$f���N'���I�$�31��N
}�8|�$�Q�ӢTr�r�����]�1�<H
O�>���3�f�>D|C9Q'
_[c�e"n�I�[T�;���.�1edg+"ײy���_���Y�GaE��;~S�Z���sWr�:�7�

Thanks for your help.